# 403() Permission denied error on a Web-application

Tags: ajax

I'm using Kivitendo (accounting software) on a PLESK Debian12 Server.
If I try to choose a chart through the magnifiying glass (look at the picture) I run in a 403 error.
Anyone an idea what is happening there?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4MQK.png)

I have no idea what to do..

Answer (score 1):

that usually means the server did not find you authorised to do such action.  Try passing the authentication tokens during the call.

Answer (score 0):

403 is often caused by ModSecurity (in Plesk called "Web Application Firewall"). You can see the error in your error_log similar like this example:

```
[client <IP Adresse>] ModSecurity: [file /etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/tortix/modsec/50_plesk_basic_asl_rules.conf"] [line "258"] [id "33350147"] [rev "143"] [msg "Protected by Atomicorp.com Basic Non-Realtime WAF Rules: Potentially Untrusted Web Content Detected"] [data ""] [severity "CRITICAL"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "rx ((?:submit(?:\\\\+| )?(request)?(?:\\\\+| )?>+|<<(?:\\\\+| )remove|(?:sign ?in|log ?(?:in|out)|next|modifier|envoyer|add|continue|weiter|account|results|select)?(?:\\\\+| )?>+)$|^< ?\\\\??(?: |\\\\+)?xml|^<samlp|^>> ?$)" against "ARGS:actions" required. [hostname "<Domain>"] [uri "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"] [unique_id "YGd3IS-RaDMGEBt0BJbDcABAAAn"], referer: https:// <Domain>/wp-admin/post.php?post=24&action=elementor
```

Look for the rule id like in this example "... [id "33350147"]  ..." and add this rule ID as an exception to the Web Application Firewall.

Another cause can be that the requested resource is a directory, and that directory (path) is empty or does not have an index file.

Comment: many thanks for the answer. The answer hits the nail on the head. A rule in SQLi was violated.